# Using IDX feed to display agent's and listings with agent's info associated for Real Estate Website

Tags: user-meta

Trying to figure out how to get a user/agent to be associated with their IDX/mls number.

Have been trying to find a way around this since Diverse Solutions does not give a feed for agent's info, only REIN(Virginia's MLS) has the agent's photo and listings associated. No real estate themes have the main search function pulling properties/agents from an IDX feed. Many themes say they are integrated with this functionality but I have purchased about 10 of them even after asking and then am told otherwise after purchasing.

For now I am just trying to be able to have a custom HTML widget for each user on my site http://erarepros.com/author/bjill/.

How can I add a custom widget for each agent/user?

Diverse Solutions provides a way to get a feed for each agent using their MLS ID
http://erarepros.com/idx/?idx-q-ListingAgentID%3C0%3E=7994
--where 7994 is the agent's REIN ID number

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Diverse Solutions, however you may need more than one product, depending on how you set it up.

First, you'll need to use our [mapping IDX](http://www.diversesolutions.com/product/ds-search-agent/tour/introduction) product dsSearchAgent to create a custom filter (we call these "links") for each agent.  Just login to your Control Panel, select "Links" from the dsSearchAgent dropdown menu, and then create a link that filters by agent ID.  You can create as many of these links as you'd like, so you can easily do one for each agent in your office.

Once you have your custom links setup, you can generate an IDX widget for each custom link you built.  You can use generate an HTML widget with dsSearchAgent from your Control Panel (this widget can be used anywhere) or you can generate a WordPress-specific widget with our [dsIDXpress IDX plugin](http://www.diversesolutions.com/idx/idx-plugin-for-wordpress) from your WordPress admin.  Either way, you can set the widget to filter listings based on any of your saved links.

dsSearchAgent is sold separately from dsIDXpress, so if you don't already have dsSearchAgent on your account, our customer service reps (or sales reps) can show you how this works in greater detail.